# Add an icon in Css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an icon under div(x) and on top of line but it's not showing in my browser. What is wrong?

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; color:#ccc; box-shadow:0px 0px
  10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"></hr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the (I assume) font awesome icons, you need to download the fonts library include the library in your html.

i.e-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

(this is the link to the font awesome CDN from bootstrap. you can (and should) save the library locally and have a local link there instead)